# Binding events via $.Ajax won't show on the calendar

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I've to do maintenance on an existing MVC app which is using an old version of FullCalendar (we're talking of 1.6.4).
As the latest commit, the view was passing the data as View's load via Model so the event where loaded in this way:

```
  $('#divAgenda').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        editable: false,
        disableDragging: true,
        events: eventsJson, 
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            eventDetail(calEvent.IdsEventi, calEvent.tipo, calEvent.start);
        },

function EventsJsonFunc() {
    var events = '<%= Html.Raw(Model.EventiJson) %>';

    return jQuery.parseJSON(events);
}
```

Now I've moved the loading at a ComboBox event change (since I've to filter the data I need to show) as

```
var dropdownlist = $('#divAgendaFilter').kendoComboBox({
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            dataSource: data,

            select: function (e) {
                if (e.item) {
                    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%= Url.Action("LoadData", "Agenda")%>',
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            userId: '<%= Request.QueryString["userId"] == null ? string.Empty : Request.QueryString["userId"].ToString() %>',
                        selectedFilter: dataItem.value
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var calendar = $('#divAgenda').data("fullCalendar");

                   //     var items = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        calendar.events=data;
                        debugger;

                    }
                });
            }
```

In `data` I've got the events but after assigning them nothing happens... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: calendar.events won't do anything, it's not a public property of the calendar. Read the documentation, which tells you what properties and methods are you exposed. You need to use RemoveEvents to remove the previous event data, and then RenderEvents to add the new versions. Or better still, just use a dynamic event data source in the first place, and then you can just call refetchEvents when you want to trigger a manual fetch from the server (e.g. as a result of your combobox changing

Comment: but calling the RenderEvents would load data at its the first load and I want to exclude this.

Comment: ?? what do you mean by "first load"? You'd call it inside your "success" function where you now (uselessly) write `calendar.events = data`. It's just the correct way of doing what you're doing now.

Comment: P.S. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/removeEvents, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/renderEvent, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/events-json-feed (for your case, pay attention to the "dynamic data parameter" section) - or alternatively https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/events-function if you need more flexibility), and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/refetchEvents,  for reference to what I've referred to above. Also worth considering upgrading to the latest version, it makes some of these tasks a little easier or with more options.

Comment: Using the JSON or function-based data feed would certainly cause data to be requested when the calendar is first created, yes...but you could set it to send parameters such that the server returns no data at all until it gets a value from the combobox, or you could set it to a certain default value. Lots of ways to deal with that

Comment: I can't update to latest right now since I also have to update the jquery from 1.9 to 3.x... I'll try your suggestions, thanks

Comment: you can just update jQuery to 2.0 at minimum actually (again, it's in the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/support), and the only change there is to drop support for IE8 and below. As https://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/ notes: "jQuery 2.0 is API-compatible with 1.9". So the jQuery version is not a reason to delay upgrading fullCalendar, unless for some unfortunate reason you still have to support IE8.

Comment: Updating it to the latest version, it works... I still have got some issue with chrome (the layout isn't correct) but I think it's a problem on my side